# Bootstrap table sorting and pagination is not working when i use jquery reveal popup plugin

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't understand why both Bootstrap table and jquery reveal popup plugin is not working together.

If I remove this line `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>` then Bootstrap sorting and pagination is not working !

if I remove this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>` then popup plugin is not working !

**Html Head section code:**

```
<!--for bootstrap table-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var name = $('td', this).eq(0).text();

    } );
} );
</script>
<!--for bootstrap table end here-->


<!-- for popup box -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/reveal.css">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<!-- for popup box end here -->
```

**Html Body section code**

```
<!--for popup box-->
<div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal3">
</div>
<a id="join_now" class="big-link2" data-reveal-id="myModal2">Popup</a>
<!--for popup box end here-->

<!--for bootstrap table with sorting and pagiantion option-->
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Kit type</th>                          
        </tr>                             
    </thead>                
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
            <td>data4</td>
            <td>data5</td>
            <td>data6</td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>    
</table>
<!--for bootstrap table with sorting and pagiantion option end here-->
```

Comment: you are using two versions of jquery..

Comment: @Reigel which one I've to remove ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any one `jquery`.
Include this to the start of `head` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
```

As `jquery.dataTables.js` is a plugin it requires `jquery-1.6.min.js` in first.